# Enbale HSTS when using Istio in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, istio, hsts, istio-gateway

I have installed istio-gateway using helm charts in AWS EKS. I am able to reach application using AWS alb and gateway. Configured virtualservice for traffic route.

For security purpose I tried enabling HSTS but its not enabling it and I could see HSTS headers in browser too.

Below is the virtualservice config I have used

```
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: serviceA
        port:
          number: 80
      headers:
        response:
          set:
            Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: Did you check this : https://www.wagner-dev.com/istio-configure-strict-transport-security-hsts.html ?

Comment: Yes I followed this and was able to achieve when I installed istio using istioctl. But I needs to use terraform for automation so relied on helm charts and installed istio(istiod,istio-base,istio-ingress charts).

My thought is only when I use helm charts it’s not working. I could see STS headers in both curl and browser inspect only not in any online test suites.